# How to disable RactiveJS's debug mode when using RequireJS?

Tags: requirejs, ractivejs

I'm aware of the minifier snippet to disable RactiveJS's debug mode.

```
Ractive.DEBUG = /unminified/.test(function(){/*unminified*/});
```

However, I'm not sure where to add it if I use RequireJS since Ractive is not a global there. I tried using a shim configuration and change Ractive.DEBUG to false in a callback function, but then I run into problems using the rv plugin because RactiveJS is not supposed to work with shim?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd put it just north of wherever you call `new Ractive()`. Sorry, I don't know RequireJS, so I can't really suggest anything idiomatic.

Comment: Yep, Chris is right – as long as `Ractive.DEBUG` is set before the first instance is created, you won't get those messages. In many cases this means including it in your `main.js`, even if you wouldn't otherwise require Ractive there, then you can set `Ractive.DEBUG` to false before anything else happens in your app.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve it using the following in the build file:

```
onBuildRead: function (moduleName, path, contents) {
    if (moduleName === 'ractive') {
        return contents.replace(
             'DEBUG: { writable: true, value: true }',
             'DEBUG: { writable: true, value: false }'
        );
    }
    return contents;
},
```

However, this feels sluggish because it alters the original file.